# Select statement to do a left join between tables, while filtering the results based on specific values in the right table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need an SQL Server Select statement to perform a left join between tables that filters the results based on specific values in the right table.

Here is an example:
The left table will hold color values. The right table will hold rows for the color combination of the left table.

```
tblObject /*this is the left table */
objID    objName
1        Violet
2        Rose 
3        Grass
4        Sky
5        Magenta

tblColorCombination /*this is the right table */
ccID    objID     Color
1       1         Red
2       1         Blue
3       2         Red
4       3         Green
5       4         Blue
6       5         Blue
7       5         Red
```

The select should return the tblObject rows with 'Red', 'Blue' combination in the tblColorCombination

```
ccID    obj ID    objName   Color
1       1         Violet    Red
2       1         Violet    Blue
6       5         Magenta   Blue
7       5         Magenta   Red
```

I tried this query but failed to filter out the Rose and sky in the right table

```
SELECT T1.ccID, T0.objID, T0.objName, T1.Color
FROM tblObject T0
LEFT JOIN tblColorCombination T1 ON T1.objID = T0.objID AND T1.Color IN ('Red', 'Blue')
```

Comment: I think you're trying to get which objID rows in the right table ONLY contain color of 'Red' and 'Blue' - SQL joins operate per-row, so your query returns everything, but only gives you back those that appear in the left table and values 'Red' and 'Blue' in the right table

Comment: You haven't explained the task in detail. So far, you are showing all objects that have both colors red and blue, but your sample data lacks a case where an object has more than these two colors, say red + blue + green. Would you want to show these objects, too?

Comment: Using a left outer join here doesn't seem to make any sense. An outer join keeps rows that have no match. I don't see such a requirement in this task.

Comment: What I'm after is to get the rows in tblObject that have both 'Red' and 'Blue' related rows in tblColorComination. I was able to have a work around using STRING_AGG, Group By and outer Select. I'll post the final query.

Comment: You do notice that you haven't answered the red + blue + green question? With SQL queries it is essential to specify *exactly* what you want to select, otherwise your results may look fine now, but some day with different data you may get undesired results.

Comment: The Grass record needs to be filtered out since it doesn't have any Red or Blue. The Rose needs to be filtered out although it has Red, it doesn't have Blue. The Sky needs to be filtered out although it has Blue, it doesn't have Red. The Violet and Magenta, both have to be filtered in since they have both Red and Blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `LEFT JOIN` (and `RIGHT JOIN` for that matter) have specific meanings in SQL: they both refer to an `OUTER JOIN` and is not what you want here.

It was not clear from your question, if you are seeking those records from tblObject that have both red and blue and no other, or all records that have at least red and blue.  If you want the latter, then the following approach is relatively simple to understand:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ccRed.ccID AS redID, ccBlue.ccID as blueId, o.objName, 
    ccRed.Color as redColor, ccBlue.Color as blueColor 
    FROM tblObject o
    INNER JOIN tblColorCombination ccRed ON ccRed.objID = o.objID AND ccRed.Color = 'Red'
    INNER JOIN tblColorCombination ccBlue ON ccBlue.objID = o.objID AND ccBlue.Color = 'Blue'
)
SELECT redID as ccID, objName, redColor as Color
FROM cte
UNION
SELECT blueID as ccID, objName, blueColor as Color
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1;
```

By way of explanation, the CTE finds records that exist with both colours by means of two inner joins to the same table, each with a different extra characteristic - Color.  The only records with red and blue are the only ones to meet the double join.

We then do a `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` to split the combined values in the CTE back to separate records.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to get those rows only which occur with **both** colors, `Red` **and** `blue` and additionaly filter out such rows that occur with **other** colors, too. This can for example be done using a CTE like this:

```
WITH redBlue AS
(SELECT 
tcc.ccID, tbo.objID, tbo.objName, tcc.color,
COUNT(CASE WHEN tcc.color = 'Red' THEN 1 END) 
  OVER(PARTITION BY tcc.objID) AS countRed,
COUNT(CASE WHEN tcc.color = 'Blue' THEN 1 END) 
  OVER(PARTITION BY tcc.objID)  AS countBlue
FROM tblObject tbo
INNER JOIN tblColorCombination tcc
ON tbo.objID = tcc.objID
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblColorCombination 
                WHERE objID = tcc.objID 
                  AND color NOT IN ('Red','Blue')))
SELECT ccId, objId, objName, color 
  FROM redBlue WHERE LEAST(countRed, countBlue) > 0;
```

The `NOT EXISTS` part filters out entries having other colors. The count conditions make sure to only get those entries which have both colors at least once.

This is the result created by the CTE query:

| ccID | obj ID | objName | Color | countRed | countBlue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Violet | Red | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Violet | Blue | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Rose | Red | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 4 | Sky | Blue | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | Magenta | Blue | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 | Magenta | Red | 1 | 1 |

The complete query produces following result for your sample data:

| ccID | obj ID | objName | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Violet | Red |
| 2 | 1 | Violet | Blue |
| 6 | 5 | Magenta | Blue |
| 7 | 5 | Magenta | Red |

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TYAkJe_m)

If it is intended to check an exact number of occurences rather than just both should be > 0, then the last part `LEAST(countRed, countBlue) > 0` can be changed to something like `countRed = 1 AND countBlue = 1`.

Note: Depending on your exact requirements and data, the `WHERE` clause of the CTE query is not required and the result will still be the same without that part. See the sample fiddle. It show when this makes a difference and when not. It's up to you what exactly you need.

Comment: This looks good. i'll give it a try. much obliged...